# Training word2vec model streaming data from file and tokenize to sentence

Tags: python, streaming, nltk, gensim, word2vec

I need to process a large number of `txt` files for building a `word2vec` model.
Now, my txt-files are a bit messy and I need to remove all ´`\n`´ newlines, read all sentences from my loaded string (txt-file) and then tokenize each sentence for using the word2vec model.

The thing is: I cant read the files line-by-line, cause some sentences do not end after one line. Therefore, I use ´`nltk.tokenizer.tokenize()`´, which splits the file into sentences.

> I cant figure out, how to convert a list of strings into a list of list, where each sub-list contains the sentences, while passing it thourgh a generator.

Or do I actually need to save each sentences into a new file (one sentence per line) to pass it through a generator?

Well, my code looks like this:
´`tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')`

```
# initialize tokenizer for processing sentences

class Raw_Sentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for file in file_loads: ## Note: file_loads includes directory name of files (e.g. 'C:/Users/text-file1.txt')
            with open(file,'r', encoding='utf-8') as t:     
               # print(tokenizer.tokenize(t.read().replace('\n', ' ')))           
                storage = tokenizer.tokenize(t.read().replace('\n', ' '))
# I tried to temporary store the list of sentences to a list for an iteration
                for sentence in storage:
                    print(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
                    yield nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)´
```

So the goal is: 
load file 1: ´`'some messy text here. And another sentence'`´
 tokenize into sentences ´`['some messy text here','And another sentence']`´
and then split each sentence into words ´`[['some','messy','text','here'],['And','another','sentence']]`´

load file 2: `'some other messy text. sentence1. sentence2.'`
etc.

and input sentences into word2vec model:
´`sentences = Raw_Sentences(directory)`´

´`model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences)`´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... after writing it all down and reconsideration... I assume I solved my own question. **Please correct me if Iam wrong:**

To iterate over every sentence created by the nltk punkt sentence tokenizer, one has to pass it directly to the for loop:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for file in file_loads:
       with open(file,'r') as t:
           for sentence in tokenizer.tokenize(t.read().replace('\n',' ')):
                yield nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
```

as always, theres also the alternative to  `yield gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(sentence, deacc= True)`

Feeding that into `sentence = Raw_Sentences(directory)`  builds a proper working Word2Vec `gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences)`